# using newer Build Tools in Windows 10 without Visual Studio

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile my `.cpp` file where I'm using `<filesystem>`.
I just downloaded newest version of `BuildTools`, using -> `Select x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2019` .
so I try to `cl myfile.cpp` and en error says:
`The contents of <filesystem> are available only with C++17 or later.`
Do I not have already 2019 version?

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110
```

Comment: Version of visual studio is a separate thing from the C++ standard revision.

Comment: thanks for explaining, is there a way to upgrade it?

Comment: I suspect that there is. I recommend checking the documentation.

Comment: @MarcelKopera You don't need to upgrade anything, just tell the compiler to use [`/std:c++17`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=vs-2019), otherwise it defaults to C++14 compliance.

Comment: thanks, but how could I tell it to compiler, when I don't have VS? I'm using command line and when I add it there, it is ignored

Comment: cl /std::c++17 myfile.cpp

Comment: Just `cl /std:c++17 myfile.cpp`, no `::` double colon.

Comment: This still happens when creating a "Windows Desktop Application" in the latest VS 2019. Sure to have changed in VS2022.